# Read XLSX file using apache POI. Null Exception

Tags: java, file, xlsx

So this is the version of code  I have now. Any I am getting a null pointer exception in line

```
wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
```

and I don't know how to resolve it. The input stream has data and even in the case input stream is not null, its throwing me the exception. 
Any help is appreciated.

Any help is appreciated.Any help is appreciated.Any help is appreciated.Any help is appreciated.Any help is appreciated.Any help is appreciated.Any help is appreciated.Any help is appreciated.

```
public String randomAcessFile(int startPosition, int length, String filePath) {
        filePath = "133837_UBC_KP_F_2_tst.xlsx";
        String textFromFile = "";
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
            if (filePath.endsWith("xlsx")) {
                /*
                 * try { workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream); textFromFile
                 * = readExcel(startPosition, length, workbook); } catch
                 * (IOException e) { System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                 * EdgarLogger.LOGGER.warning(e.getMessage()); }
                 */
                XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
                try {
                    wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
                    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
                    XSSFRow row = null;
                    XSSFCell cell = null;
                    Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
                    int rowIndex = -1;
                    while (rows.hasNext() && rowIndex != startPosition) {
                        row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                    if (rowIndex != startPosition || row == null) {
                        return "";
                    }
                    Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
                    int colIndex = -1;
                    while (cells.hasNext() && colIndex != length) {
                        cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                        colIndex++;
                    }
                    if (colIndex != length || cell == null) {
                        return "";
                    }
                    if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                        return cell.getStringCellValue() + " ";
                    } else if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        return cell.getNumericCellValue() + " ";
                    } else if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                        return "" + cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                    } else {
                        return "";
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    EdgarLogger.LOGGER.warning(e.getMessage());
                }
                /*
                 * while (rows.hasNext()) { row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
                 * Iterator cells = row.cellIterator(); while (cells.hasNext())
                 * { cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                 * 
                 * if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                 * System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " "); } else if
                 * (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                 * System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " "); } else {
                 * // U Can Handel Boolean, Formula, Errors } }
                 * System.out.println(); }
                 */
            } else if (filePath.endsWith("xls")) {
                HSSFWorkbook wb;
                try {
                    wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
                    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
                    HSSFRow row = null;
                    HSSFCell cell = null;
                    Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
                    int rowIndex = -1;
                    while (rows.hasNext() && rowIndex != startPosition) {
                        row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                        rowIndex++;
                    }
                    if (rowIndex != startPosition || row == null) {
                        return "";
                    }
                    Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
                    int colIndex = -1;
                    while (cells.hasNext() && colIndex != length) {
                        cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                        colIndex++;
                    }
                    if (colIndex != length || cell == null) {
                        return "";
                    }
                    if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                        return cell.getStringCellValue() + " ";
                    } else if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                        return cell.getNumericCellValue() + " ";
                    } else if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                        return "" + cell.getBooleanCellValue();
                    } else {
                        return "";
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    EdgarLogger.LOGGER.warning(e.getMessage());
                }
                /*
                 * int[] row_col = getRowCol(workbook); if (row_col[0] - 1 <
                 * startPosition || row_col[1] - 1 < length) { return ""; } Cell
                 * cell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(startPosition)
                 * .getCell(length); switch (cell.getCellType()) { case
                 * Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: return cell.getStringCellValue(); case
                 * Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: return "" +
                 * cell.getNumericCellValue(); case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                 * return "" + cell.getBooleanCellValue(); default: return ""; }
                 */
            } else {
                RandomAccessFile file;
                try {
                    file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
                    try {
                        file.seek(startPosition);
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
                        file.read(bytes);
                        file.close();
                        textFromFile = new String(bytes);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        EdgarLogger.LOGGER.warning(e.getMessage());
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    EdgarLogger.LOGGER.warning(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                EdgarLogger.LOGGER.warning(e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            EdgarLogger.LOGGER.warning(e.getMessage());
        }
        return textFromFile;
    }
```

Comment: The `InputStream` is null.

Comment: But I update it in the try catch block. Should it get updated after that?

Comment: What happens if the file isn't found? You print a warning and continue.

Comment: I got your point so, I added the latter code block inside the try block but even though I am getting an  null exception.

Comment: Updated the code to have the latest copy. Could you please have a look?
 @chrylis